# Any ideas on how to truncate the strings on both sides like in the picture? WITH ONLY CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried to truncate the string with:

- **white-space: nowrap**
- **overflow: hidden**
- **text-overflow: clip**

but it's only one side even the direction CSS property. Also tried the **transform: translateX()**, but it move the whole block without moving the hidden text.
Also, I googled something like "static ticker", but that isn't it.

**Maybe**, I need to use **flex/grid** rows with 3 columns for each string and truncate the first and last columns?

Screenshot from Figma:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7eYf.png

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.content {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <p class="content">
      blah blah blah<br>
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
   </p>
</div>
```